# npm install fibers shows error

Tags: node.js, node-fibers

When i  try to install fibers using **npm install** fibers i've got following error, Also i tried with other solutions in the stack overflow but none of them is helped, please help

Iam using OSX 10.8.5

```
> fibers@1.0.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at F    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:43:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at E    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:46:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:16
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-             

gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed
npm ERR! fibers@1.0.1 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "fibers@1.0.1" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/mac/Documents/node/node-fibers
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mac/Documents/node/node-fibers/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: you need to install "make" in order to install these modules. Sadly I cant tell you how to do this on a Mac.

Comment: I have make on mine, but it isn't installing. Similar error, fibers being the culprit

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools    
npm install --global node-gyp
```

Comment: How does this help the op if they said they're using OSX?

Comment: it works for windows. I am using the latest node version as of 31-Oct-2020

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I couldn't install fibers because I used not a correct version of node. I used node 10.
From fibers [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers#supported-platforms):

> If you are running NodeJS version 4.x, 5.x, or 6.x on Linux, OS X, or
>   Windows (7 or later) then you should be able to install fibers from
>   npm just fine. If you are running an older (or newer) version of node
>   or some other operating system you will have to compile fibers on your
>   system.

So I downgraded to node 6.
And it got installed just fine.

```
npm i fibers@1.0.15
```

Comment: AMAZING -- this worked great, I had been putting something in a config file and it wasn't fully working. This explicit command saved the day.

I used specifically: npm i fibers@4.0.3

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same situation but in Ubuntu, ASHISH RANJAN solved for me the lack of `node-gyp` and I could successfully install it (thanks!). But by your log I could say you're missing `make`.

I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Node 10 and this is what I did:

- Install `gcc`, `g++`, `make` and `build-essential` just to be sure.
- `npm install -g node-gyp`

I don't know much of OSX but I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I was using node 15.10.
I unninstall it and install the LTS (14.16) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For folks who want to upgrade Node to 10 and above, you will have to find dependencies out of date with Node 10 and upgrade these packages to newer stable version, then build (npm/yarn install).

Answer (score 0):

I've "fibers": "3.1.1".
So I uninstalled node 14 and installed node 11.
**and it worked.**

Answer (score 0):

I want to expand on the answer of [@Mahmoud.Ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67685618/777885).

On Mac (Big Sur), I had this error with the `npm run build` (for Webpack) command:

```
## There is an issue with `node-fibers` ##
`/app/node_modules/fibers/bin/darwin-x64-67/fibers.node` is missing.

Try running this to fix the issue: /Users/[username]/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.2/bin/node /app/node_modules/fibers/build
```

I think it happened from switching Node versions (with NVM).

My solution:

1. Switch to Node v11 (for Fibers 3.1.1 compatibility) e.g. `nvm i 11 ; nvm use 11`
2. Remove your node_modules directory
3. Reinstall: `npm i`
4. Re-run your npm command e.g. `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled higher version of nodejs and reinstalled a lower version (14.x) and npm install worked without issues.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Usually duplicate answers are not allowed in [StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415351/duplicate-answers-in-low-quality-answers-re-flag-or-delete) (I count at least 3 answers telling to install another node version), mainly if it is a late answer like yours.

Answer (score 0):

`fibers` doesn't support nodejs v16+ due to a breaking change in the v8 engine.

It is now recommended to just use the `sass` package without `fibers`.

[Source: webpack.js.org](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#:%7E:text=Fibers%20is%20not%20compatible%20with%20Node.js%20v16.0.0%20or%20later.%20Unfortunately%2C%20v8%20commit%20dacc2fee0f%20is%20a%20breaking%20change%20and%20workarounds%20are%20non%2Dtrivial.%20(see%20introduction%20to%20readme).)